# (android) : creating a application using json

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying the application program using json.what is the uses of json_decode in android.How can i use the json_decode in my application? is it possible means tell some idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be best to ask on a forum like [App Dev Forum](http://www.appdevroom.com) or similar as this is not the sort of question we like to answer on StackOverflow. You really need to research these things yourself or give us a code snippet for us to check out. This is more of a strictly programming related community.

Answer (score 0):

It would be MUCH easier if you used [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). It automatically maps JSON to your classes.